# Convert locations from ECEF NED (local coordinate system) to WGS 84 (global coordinate system)

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, datum, ned

I track relative positions to known fixed reference location (Lat/Lon/Alt on WGS 84).

Which means Location_0 is the above reference location, and Location_i is something like (X,Y,Z) relative by definition to Location_0 under ECEF convention (one can think about something like INS/IMU system).

I can obtain Location_i (Lat, Lon, Alt) from (X,Y,Z) with [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) & [NED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_east_down) conversions.

But if the "distance" (for the sake of simplicity let's relax the definition of what exactly I mean by 'distance') between Location_0 & Location_i going as far as hundreds of kilometers etc. ECEF & NED assumptions not enough and I need to work with WGS 84.

How can I track positions calculated under ECEF NED assumption relatively to known referenced point on WGS84, and then convert them to WGS84?

Comment: Asking for "best practices" suggests that you are seeking a list of things that you should do or be aware of which makes this too broad for focused Q&A. Can you focus your question more?

Comment: @PolyGeo Edited

Comment: Can you assume that these longer distances are on or near the surface of the ellipsoid? Then convert Location_0 to WGS84, then use a solution to the direct / first problem of geodesy (given point, azimuth, distance, calc 2nd point). May need to find a geodesic solution that includes heights.

Comment: @mkennedy   Yes you can assume the locstions are 'on the ground'